# Error installing Ruby on Centos 7 using rvm

Tags: ruby, centos, rvm

I'm installing Ruby 2.5.0 on Centos 7 using rvm.

Howenever I run `rvm install ruby-2.5.0` I get the following error in compiling stage:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j1',
please read /home/(username)/.rvm/log/1519585487_ruby-2.5.0/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

In `/home/(username)/.rvm/log/1519585487_ruby-2.5.0/make.log` I found in the compiling section:

```
compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
generating miniprelude.c
executable host ruby is required. use --with-baseruby option.
make: *** [miniprelude.c] Error 1
++ return 2
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What does `which ruby` return? Do you /have/ a ruby to start with?

Comment: ```/usr/bin/which: no ruby in .... ``` . No Ruby versions were installed.

Comment: There were a few search results on this at https://www.google.com/search?q=executable+host+ruby+is+required.+use+--with-baseruby+option.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab.

Comment: I already made searches for a solution to this problem. However, I found one of the links in your search useful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @Keith Bennet . I found a solution.

The solution (which is extremely ridiculous) was to install ruby using `yum install ruby` and then try again to run `rvm use ruby-2.5.0` . Worked like charm.